# Is my understanding of compounded/conditional probability correct?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to understand from an *intuitive* perspective the computation of compounded probability.
Say we have one event which can return multiple outcomes and I'm interested in 3 outcomes ($a$, $b$ and $c$).
We have $p(a) + p(b) + p(c) <= 1$; these events are mutually exclusive.

Suppose we get three executions, then the probability of getting all $a$ and $b$ and $c$ in *any* order would be:

$p(a)*p(b)*p(c) * factorial(3)$

I would interpret the above as the odds of getting $a$ then $b$ and then $c$ and then multiplied for all their permutations (i.e. $a b c$ or $a c b$ or $b a c$ and so on - for a total of 6).

Now suppose I execute a fourth try and I want to compute the odds of getting at least one of $a$ and $b$ and $c$ after four executions (not just three).

I'm trying to logically come up with the probability of such scenario, and this is my thought process. The total probability would be:

1. The same as above $p(a)*p(b)*p(c)*6$ for cases when we get desired outcome with first three executions - we still do the fourth but we have already satisfied having $a$, $b$ and $c$
2. Then we need to *add* the odds of when we have the first three executions and $a$ doesn't happen but it happens in the fourth execution, so $p(1-a)*p(b)*p(c)*6*p(a)$
3. Then we need to *add* the odds of when we have the first three executions and $b$ doesn't happen but it happens in the fourth execution, so $p(a)*p(1-b)*p(c)*6*p(b)$
4. Finally we need to *add* the odds of when we have the first three executions and $c$ doesn't happen but it happens in the fourth execution, so $p(a)*p(b)*p(1-c)*6*p(c)$

So the final equation (after some rearrangement and simplification) would be:

$p(a)*p(b)*p(c)*6*(1 + (1-a) + (1-b) + (1-c))$

Is my understanding/reasoning correct?

If we were to add a fifth execution, then the equation would be:

$p(a)*p(b)*p(c)*6*(1 + (1-a) + (1-b) + (1-c) + (1-a)^2 + (1-b)^2 + (1-c)^2)$

Am I getting this right?

Thanks!

Comment: If $A, B, C$ are _mutually exclusive_ events, then it is _very definitely_ **not** the case that $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$.  The generally accepted meaning of $P(A\mid B$) is the _conditional probability_ of $A$ _given_ that $B$ occurred, but _mutual exclusion_ means that the occurrence of $B$ _precludes_ the occurrence of $A$: if $B$ has occurred, then $A$ cannot possibly have occurred. Thus, $P(A\mid B)$equals $0$, and not $P(A)$, unless of course $P(A)$ happens to have  value $0$.  But then by similar arguments, we would need to conclude that $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ also have value $0$.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the difference between independence and mutual exclusion?

Comment: I think you're correct in terms of mutually exclusive events - a bit like rolling a dice, if you get a 4, you can't possibly get a 5 with the same roll. I'll update the question removing confusing part. Still, what about the main discussion points?

Comment: A very general answer is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288073.  Briefly: use multinomial coefficients.

Comment: Thanks about the suggestion - but I'm really after if my reasoning is correct/logically has some foundations or not - and if not why/where is it wrong? I'm truly trying to understand this topic.